# What are Private Servers?

Tags: clash-of-clans, terminology

I have seen a couple questions recently asking about private servers for Clash of Clans. I looked them up online, and I can't find any information about them, only sites offering them. What are these private servers? Are they even legitimate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question as nothing to do with gaming. What are Private Servers doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Lokuzt I don't think it's off topic - if the OP wanted to know *how* to create a private server, that might be off-topic. However since the OP is only looking to find out what they are, that is on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A private server is a server not hosted by SuperCell that you can connect to to play if you root/jailbreak your mobile device to edit the host file to allow you to access a different IP address with the game. You can get unlimited resources and gems on some private servers.

As for if they are legitimate, it depends on your definition, they exist, but are most likely not legal. I am not a lawyer, but Supercell's [TOS](http://supercell.com/en/terms-of-service/) seem to forbid this, specifically in section 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they don't exist, given how Supercell operates. Their games can only be played on the servers that they provide. Any site offering a server is as legitimate as a site offering cheaper gems - it's a complete scam!

I even doubt a modded app would be able to run on a server that is not Supercell's.

To conclude there's a reason those questions are locked, and it's not only the rules! :D